# Ansible mount with state: mounted not working for sshfs

Tags: state, ubuntu-18.04, mount

I want to add a sshfs entry to my fstab on Ubuntu 18.04 using ansible.

Ansible changes my fstab and adds the correct line for mounting the remote sshfs filesystem. But `state: mounted` does not work. It will not be mounted. Do you have any ideas why?

```
- name: Adding fstab entry for borg remote mount point
  mount:
    path: /home/borg/backups-remote
    src: borg@myserver.com:/users/borg
    fstype: fuse.sshfs
    opts: "defaults,allow_other,_netdev,idmap=user,follow_symlinks,identityfile=/home/borg/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid={{ borg_user.uid }},gid={{ borg_user.group }}"
    state: mounted
  register: backup_remote
```

Comment: There is a detailed description available on GitHub: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/67966